# Google translator in textbox not working for https site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, google-translator-toolkit

i used google translator for textbox. its working as excepted but when i moved to production it's showing

> *"The page at 'https://myexample.org/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text=kamla&ime=transliteration_en_ta&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=jsapi&uv&cb=_callbacks_._0je9phncp'.
>   This request has been blocked;"*

so how to convert translator url **http to https** and my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
<title> Transliteration Help </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "transliteration"});
</script> 
<style>
    .inputapi-transliterate-indic-suggestion-menu{
        z-index: 100;
    }
</style>
<script>
function OnLoad() {
 var currValue = document.getElementById("txtTranslator");                               
 var options = {
                 sourceLanguage:
                 google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
                destinationLanguage:
                [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.TAMIL],
                shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
                transliterationEnabled: true
};
var control = new
google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
control.makeTransliteratable(["txtTranslator"]);
var postValue = document.getElementById("txtTranslator"); 

} //end onLoad function
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script> 
</head>
    <body>
    <input size="40" type="text" id="txtTranslator"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you try changing the src in script import to: `src="//www.google.com/jsapi"`? Notice that I have removed `http:` from it.

Comment: try changing `src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"` to `src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"`

Comment: same still am getting the same error in this URL 'http://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text=kamla&ime=transliteration_en_ta&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=jsapi&uv&cb=_callbacks_._0je9phncp"

Comment: any other better way to achieve this?

Comment: is tht resolved? me too facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Open the https://www.google.com/jsapi and copy paste the code locally.
Change the URL's with http to https.Include this file in your code.

Also remove this code if you're using it

/* google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });  */